# store a composit function name in a dictionary without being a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, menu

I have a python3.8 dictionary of menu commands, I am attempting to add the functions to another dictionary, using the menu name in the function. so 'save' becomes 'self.menu_save' unfortunately when I save it with concatenation like 'self.menu_' + menuname  I get a string in my dictionary that is not executable,  I could manually type the names and it would work however I am building a class and the menu names are entered from the subclass
I would like to be able to do this:

```
self.pri_menu = {'file': ['save', 'new', 'open', 'delete', 'print'],
                         'edit': ['select', "update", 'delete', 'insert']}
```

and then iterate: and end up with
{'save': self.menu_save, 'new':self.menu_new,...}
my current attempts leave me with
{save:'self.menu_save','new':'self.menu_new',...}

```
     self.menu_commands[y] = 'self.menu_' + y
     self.menu_items[row].add_command(label=y, command=self.menu_commands[y])
```

this does not work.  Y is my Iterator so 'save' etc..
print(self.menu_commands) =

{'save': 'self.menu_save', 'new': 'self.menu_new', 'open': 'self.menu_open', 'delete': 'self.menu_delete', 'print': 'self.menu_print', 'select': 'self.menu_select', 'update': 'self.menu_update', 'insert': 'self.menu_insert'}

I am doing this within a class so the references / pointers have to be in the class I am thinking there may be an interpreter que or something to let the system know this is a function and look it up, and not just string. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'self.menu_' + y
self.commands[y] = eval(x)
self.menu_items[row].add_command(label=y, command=self.commands[y])
```

Works great, thanks,  just needed the correct search words and google helped me out.  and now I can also use the commands without needing the menu like
self.commands['save'] or self.commands.get('save') yay python.

my next problem should be adding args to the functions but another day.